# Plot clusters of similar words from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, cluster-analysis

I have a big dataframe, here's a small subset:

```python
key_words  prove      have      read   represent  lead   replace  
be         0.58       0.49      0.48     0.17     0.23   0.89   
represent  0.66       0.43      0        1        0      0.46   
associate  0.88       0.23      0.12     0.43     0.11   0.67   
induce     0.43       0.41      0.33     0.47     0      0.43
```

Which shows how close each word from the `key_words` is to the rest of the columns (based on their embeddings distance).

I want to find a way to visualize this dataframe so that I see the clusters that are being formed among the words that are closest to each other.

Is there a simple way to do this, considering that the `key_word` column has string values?

Answer (score 0):

One option is to set the key_words column as index and to use [`seaborn.clustermap`](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html) to plot the clusters:

```
# pip install seaborn
import seaborn as sns

sns.clustermap(df.set_index('key_words'),  # data
               vmin=0, vmax=1,    # values of min/max here white/black
               cmap='Greys',      # color palette
               figsize=(5,5)      # plot size
               )
```

output:

[image: clustermap]

Comment: I tried heatmap as well, but the dataframe is very big and I lose information. I would like to have a scatterplot, to show which words are close together. Is that possible?

Comment: @joasa how would you define the position on the scatter plot? scatter plots use continuous, not categorical, data

Comment: Yes, that's my main problem actually, if there's a way to use these categorical data from the `key_words` column as clusters and then - based on how close the rest of the words are to each cluster, create a scatterplot. Not sure if it's possible

Comment: You have to come up with an idea of representation that suits your data. Clustering is a good idea but you have to be careful in how you trim and select groups